# passing a double pointer boolean array to a function

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, graph, cycle

I have a double pointer boolean.
I would like to pass this boolean to a function

The code is used for graph theory, to create an adj matrix, check if the graph has cycles or not ...

The problem comes from the cycle function

The function doesn't like the boolean in parameter to check if a graph has a cycle.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm> 


using namespace std; 

int Cycle(int number_of_vertices ,bool **adj_matrix)
{
    bool** adj = new bool*[number_of_vertices];
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_vertices;i++)
    {
        adj[i] = new bool[number_of_vertices];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_vertices;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<number_of_vertices;j++)
        {
            adj[i][j] = adj_matrix[i+1][j+1];
        }
    }
    for(int k=0;k<number_of_vertices;k++)
    {  // transitiv closure
        for(int i=0;i<number_of_vertices;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<number_of_vertices;j++)
            {
                if(adj[i][k]&&adj[k][j])
                {
                    adj[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<number_of_vertices;i++)
    {
        if(adj[i][i])
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main()
{
    string first_line, second_line; 
    int initial_extremity, final_extremity, value, number_of_vertices, nombre_arcs;
    ifstream fichier("test.txt"); 
    bool** adj_matrix; 
    int** val_matrix; 
    vector<int> vertice_names; 

    if (fichier.is_open())
    {
        getline(fichier, first_line); 
        number_of_vertices = atoi(first_line.c_str()); 
        getline(fichier, second_line); 
        nombre_arcs = atoi(second_line.c_str()); 
        adj_matrix = new bool*[number_of_vertices]; 
        val_matrix = new int*[number_of_vertices];


        for (int i=0; i<number_of_vertices;i++)
        {
            adj_matrix[i] = new bool[number_of_vertices];
            val_matrix[i] = new int[number_of_vertices];

            for (int j=0; j<number_of_vertices; j++)
            {
                adj_matrix[i][j] = false; 
                val_matrix[i][j] = 0; 
            }
        }


        while(fichier >> initial_extremity >> final_extremity >> value)
        {
            adj_matrix[initial_extremity][final_extremity] = true;
            val_matrix[initial_extremity][final_extremity] = value;
            int c = Cycle(number_of_vertices, adj_matrix);
            printf("number of cycles: %d\n\n", c);
            if(c!=0)
            {
                printf("%d --[%d]--> %d\n",initial_extremity,value,final_extremity);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d --[%d]--> %d\n",initial_extremity,value,final_extremity);
            }

            if ( find(vertice_names.begin(), vertice_names.end(), initial_extremity) != vertice_names.end() )
            {
                //nothing
            }
            else
            {
                vertice_names.push_back(initial_extremity); 
            }
            if ( find(vertice_names.begin(), vertice_names.end(), final_extremity) != vertice_names.end() )
            {
                //nothing
            }
            else
            {
                vertice_names.push_back(final_extremity);
            }
        }
        fichier.close(); 
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "error while opening the file" << '\n';
        cin.get();
    }

    printf("%d arcs\n",nombre_arcs);
    printf("%d vertices\n\n\n",number_of_vertices);
    printf("Adj Matrix \n");
    printf("    ");
    for(int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d",vertice_names.at(i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d ", vertice_names.at(i));
        for (int j = 0; j <number_of_vertices; j++)
        {
            printf("%3d",adj_matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");


    sort(vertice_names.begin(), vertice_names.end(), less<int>()); 
    printf("Adj and value matrix\n");
    printf("    ");
    for(int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d",vertice_names.at(i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_vertices; i++)
    {
        printf("%3d ", vertice_names.at(i));
        for (int j = 0; j <number_of_vertices; j++)
        {
            if (adj_matrix[i][j])
            {
                printf("%3d",val_matrix[i][j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("   ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }



    return 0;
}
```

format of the .txt file:

first line : number of vertices
second : number of arcs
the other lines : Inital Arc    Final Arc    Value

```
3
4
0 1 0
1 0 12
1 2 25
2 0 6
```

By the way, if someone have a better idea to check if a graph has a cycle let me know

Best regards

Comment: Please use `std::vector<>`, and pass it by constant reference... never use such pointers in C++.

Comment: Don't think of things as "double  pointers", think of them as what they are - pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like you are stepping out of bounds in the Cycle function:

```
for(int i=0;i<number_of_vertices;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<number_of_vertices;j++)
    {
        adj[i][j] = adj_matrix[i+1][j+1]; // i + 1 and j + 1 go out of bounds
    }
}
```

Suppose `number_of_vertices` is 3. Then the index of the last element is 2. When i = 2, then i + 1 = 3. Out of bounds.